# Electromagnet connected to a blade to cut a piece of thread

Tags: electromagnetism

I am new to the site and have an idea that I would like to implement at my work place. I do not have electrical knowledge but I know people who will be able to implement an electronic system.

I have a small manufacturing company that stitches material together using sewing machines. The machines are old and I do not have funds to invest in new machinery.

I would like to create a scissors/blade that is able to cut the threads after each piece is stitched. The machine is fixed onto a desk and the thread from the sewing machine needs to be cut underneath the machine, so not visible from the top. So my thinking is the having a 2 blades underneath that is connected to a electromagnet and the operator of the machine can press a button using their foot to turn the magnet on and it would close, once the foot is released the blades open. The threads are strong but are thin, less than 1 millimeter in thickness.

I would like to keep the system very simple and cheap to create. I understand that the blades will need to be changed regularly.

Does anyone have advise with this?
Thank you

Comment: This seems more of a mechanical engineering problem than electrical, particularly if you are expecting someone else to do the electrical work. Its also rather an open-ended question, and they are often closed here.

Comment: If they can press something with their foot, you might adapt a bicycle brake lever and Bowden cable, to close scissors (and a return spring to open them). Either this or electromagnets require mechanical engineering.

Comment: The electro-magnetic-mechanical component that you described is called or is related to a solenoid. So do some searching of "solenoid".

Comment: A hot wire also can part a thread, and doesn't need moving parts.